# Spring MVC confusion

Tags: spring

Came across below code snippet for Spring MVC controller in my
project POC and below is the one of the method.
        In this case getEntityDetails will get data from database convert that data to JSON object and return it.

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/com/dbTest/testData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getEntityDetails
        (HttpSession session, @RequestParam(value="Id", required=false) String Id) throws Exception 
        {
            String userId = (String) session.getAttribute("userId");
            this.getEntity.getEntityData(userId);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Mapping for this call is done as below through Angular JS:

```
        return $http({
        url: '/com/dbTest/testData',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
        }
      });
```

I am confused here that how view in getting rendered and why ModelAndView is not used here.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

Use another constructor and pass value of this.getEntity.getEntityData(userId);

ResponseEntity(T body, HttpStatus statusCode)

Answer (score 0):

`ModelAndView` needs the view name as well as model(data) to be populated but in case of AJAX (asynchronous calls) we need not to specify view name and getting the response data is good for us. So in that case [ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)  fits well which can return `JSON/XML` view based on mapper defined in your configuration file and can be rendered on view easily as in your case.

It also gives us added flexibility in defining arbitrary [HTTP response headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses).

- `ResponseEntity(HttpStatus statusCode)`
- `ResponseEntity(MultiValueMap<String,String> headers, HttpStatus statusCode)`
- `ResponseEntity(T body, HttpStatus statusCode)`
- `ResponseEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String,String> headers,
         HttpStatus statusCode)`